# New on record with dynamic Size

Tags: memory-management, delphi-7, dynamic-arrays

If there is a record like this:

```
type myType=record 
       a : array of byte;
     end;`
     pMyType=^myType;
```

Can i get memory for this without calling `getMem` and without calculate the size by myself?

I like to use `New` but where do i specify the length of `a`?

Comment: You'll have to set the array field length manually whatever way you use for the record initialization. Could you include Delphi version tag into your question, please ?

Comment: Before i call `New`? Is this thread-safe?

Comment: No, right after you create your variable. Assume that you have a variable like `MyRecord: PMyType;`, to create the variable in memory you call `New(MyRecord);`. After that, the array field will have a 0 length because it's a managed type. To set length of that array field you will still have to call something like this `SetLength(MyRecord.a, 10);` somewhere after the variable creation. Uhm, thread-safe ? It's just a memory allocation. If you're asking if it's safe to call `New` in a thread, then yes, it is. [P.S. I'll delete my comments from here in few minutes to cleanup the *workspace*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

`New` create the record with `a`'s initial size of 0. The `SetLength` changes the used memory in Run-Time.